# Function that copies values of first (2D) array into second, using pointers

Tags: c++

My task is to:

> In your main function, define and initialise a two-dimensional double array. Define (but do not initialize) another two-dimensional double array of the same size as the first one. Write a function that copies the values of the first array into the second, this time using pointers.

I have tried:

```
void cpyda(double *old_array,double *new_array,int length){
    double *ptr_one=old_array;
    double *ptr_two=new_array;

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        ptr_two[i]=ptr_one[i];
    }

    for(int r=0;r<2;r++){
        for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
            cout<<new_array[r][c]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
   double array_one[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
   double array_two[2][3]={};
   cpyda(array_one,array_two, 6);
}
```

The errors I keep getting are:

```
 function-1-4.cpp: In function 'void cpyda(double*, double*, int)':
 function-1-4.cpp:14:33: error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array 
   subscript
              cout<<new_array[r][c]<<" ";
                             ^
 main-1-4.cpp: In function 'int main()':
 main-1-4.cpp:9:11: error: cannot convert 'double (*)[3]' to 'double*'
      cpyda(array_one,array_two, 6);
       ^~~~~~~~~
 main-1-4.cpp:4:27: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void 
 cpyda(double*, double*, int)'
 extern void cpyda(double *old_array,double *new_array,int length);
```

Comment: And this doesnt work?

Comment: I assume you are getting a compilation error. What is it? Please edit the question to include this.

Comment: If you want some tips:  
`double *ptr_one=old_array;`
`double *ptr_two=new_array;`
these lines do nothing, its more readable to keep refering to your arrays as old_array and new_aray;  
Also its usually best to separate functions to represent single tasks, in your case to make one function for copying array and second one for printing it.

Comment: @hyde sorry, edited now

Comment: The compiler error is because you have defined `new_array` as a (single) pointer, which can be implicitly treated as a **one-dimensional** array (not two). Move to `main` as I suggested and it will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would put the array output code in `main()`, after the call to `cpyda(...)` - after all, the function is only supposed to do the actual copying ...

Second, if your function should "use pointers" then really use pointers, not variables declared as pointers that are then treated as arrays ...

```
void cpyda(double *old_array,double *new_array,int length){
    double *ptr_one=old_array;
    double *ptr_two=new_array;

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    //    ptr_two[i]=ptr_one[i];
          *ptr_two++ = *ptr_one++
    }    
 }

int main(){
   double array_one[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
   double array_two[2][3]={};
   cpyda(array_one[0], array_two[0], 6);
   for (int r=0; r<2; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<3; c++) cout << array_two[r][c] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

You could also make the `cpyda` function much more succinct by not bothering to copy the pointer arguments to locals …

```
void cpyda(double *old_array,double *new_array,int length){
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) *new_array++ = *old_array++;
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi, there was 1 compilation error which was fixed by writing                                 "cpyda(*array_one, *array_two, 6)" (writing the array parameters as pointers). Thank you!

Comment: Oops! I made the same mistake as I warned you about! Adding `[0]` subscripts to the array names fixes it! As will adding the `*` prefix, as you did!

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
void cpyda(double** old_array, double ** new_array, int row, int column) 
{
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        memcpy(&new_array[r][0], &old_array[r][0], sizeof(double) * column);
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < column; c++)
        {
            std::cout << new_array[r][c] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    double** arrayOne = new double*[2];
    double** arrayTwo = new double*[2];

    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
    {
        arrayOne[r] = new double[3];
        arrayTwo[r] = new double[3];
    }

    double value = 1;

    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            arrayOne[r][c] = value++;
        }
    }
    cpyda(arrayOne, arrayTwo, 2, 3);

    for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
    {
        delete[] arrayOne[r];
        delete[] arrayTwo[r];
    }
    delete[] arrayOne;
    delete[] arrayTwo;
}
```